# Error accessing Path Analyzer admin page

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

I am getting this error when accessing the `sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx`.
As a background, we had just did a Sitecore upgrade from Sitecore 8.1 to 10.1.
Appreciate if anyone can give some insights into this one.

Thanks in advanced!

[image]

Comment: Errors and stacktraces should be included as text, never images. SEO needs something to work with.